# pandas get (start, end) positions of True values based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the below df:

```
import pandas as pd
frames = [9,12,14,15,16,17,18,22,23,24,25,30]
counter = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'frames':frames, 'counter':counter})
```

```
print(df)

    frames  counter
0        9        0
1       12        0
2       14        0
3       15        0
4       16        1
5       17        1
6       18        1
7       22        0
8       23        0
9       24        1
10      25        1
11      30        0
```

without using a for loop, how can i get the (start, end) frames where the counter is 1(True)?

result:

```
[(16,18), (24,25)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ne(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)+[`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) combined with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to group the 1s together. Then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to get the [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) value per group.

Either as a Series:

```
m = df['counter'].ne(1)

out = (df.loc[~m, 'frames']
      .groupby(m.cumsum())
      .agg(['first', 'last'])
      )
```

output:

```
         first  last
counter             
4           16    18
6           24    25
```

Or as a list of tuples with aggregation as tuples, the conversion [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
lst = (df.loc[~m, 'frames']
      .groupby(m.cumsum())
      .agg(lambda x: (x.iloc[0], x.iloc[-1]))
      .to_list()
      )
```

output:

```
[(16, 18), (24, 25)]
```

Answer (score 2):

First create mask by compare `counter`, aggregate consecutive `True`s by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)
[`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html)
and last convert to tuples:

```
m = df.counter.eq(1)

L = (df[m].groupby((m & ~m.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum())['frames']
          .agg(['first','last'])
          .agg(tuple, axis=1)
          .tolist())
print (L)
[(16, 18), (24, 25)]
```

Comment: Both solutions will do the thing, they are nice. Picked @mozway as answer because it's easier to read for me. Thank you @jezrael!